# How to add custom css with styled component and reactjs? Warning: Received false for a non-boolean attribute isfirstimageattachment

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I like to add styles based on the props.

```
import   {ArrowBackIcon} from './styles';

const App = () => {
...

  const isFirstImageAttachment = (index) => {
    return (
      filteredImages.length &&
      filteredImages[0]?.uuid === attachments[index]?.uuid
    );
  };

...

  return (
    <div className="App">
     ...

      <ArrowBackIcon
        isfirstimageattachment={isFirstImageAttachment(idx)}
        onClick={clickBackAttachment}
      />

      ...
    </div>
  );
};

)
```

styles.js

```
export const ArrowForwardIcon = styled(ForwardArrowIcon)`
  ...
  display: ${props => (props.isfirstimageattachment ? 'none' : 'block')}; ;
`;
```

`isFirstImageAttachment` is supposed to return `true` or `false` so depending on that value I like to hide or show `ArrowForwardIcon` component.

I'm getting an error saying `Warning: Received false for a non-boolean attribute isfirstimageattachment.If you want to write it to the DOM, pass a string instead: isfirstimageattachment="false" or isfirstimageattachment={value.toString()}`

I don't want to do `isfirstimageattachment="false"` because `isfirstimageattachment` doesn't always return false. Also this function doesn't return `string` so `isfirstimageattachment={value.toString()}` don't work the way I want to.

Is there any I can do?

#### Attempts

What I figured out is even though I passed string `false` style didn't change.

```
  return (
    <div className="App">
     ...

      <ArrowBackIcon
        isfirstimageattachment="false"
        onClick={clickBackAttachment}
      />

      ...
    </div>
```

I saw the element got applied `display: none;`
Is this not the way giving the props to styled component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import   {ArrowBackIcon} from './styles';

const App = () => {
...

  const isFirstImageAttachment = (index) => {
     const showEl = filteredImages.length &&
      filteredImages[0]?.uuid === attachments[index]?.uuid;
     return showEl ? 'hidden' : 'visible';
  };

...

  return (
    <div className="App">
     ...

      <ArrowBackIcon
        isfirstimageattachment={isFirstImageAttachment(idx)}
      />

      ...
    </div>
  );
};

)
```

styles.js

```
export const ArrowBackIcon = styled(BackArrowIcon)`
  visibility: ${props => props.isfirstimageattachment};
`;
```

I was able to add style dynamically this way!